# ScrolledListView in Android

Tags: android, list, scroll

I found this Image on the web and want to use a such list in android. Do you have an idea where I can find a such List in Android Studio?

[image: List]

Answer (score 0):

There are certain lists that others have provided as free source code to be used within your applications.  What you have discovered is not a built-in feature of Android (the IDE has not relevance on this).

You can however find resources to use a wheel such as those.  One of which used in the past has been from the [android-wheel](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) code.  Most will demonstrate examples and provide useful tips on going forward with implementation.  But you can find others if you look hard enough.